# Getting records from more than 2 tables using join

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

Here is my table structure:

**Table 1**

```
  id | question | posted_id
```

**Table 2**

```
  id | username | email
```

**Table 3**

```
 id | reader_id | quote_id
```

I want to fetch those question which are not read by particular user.I also want email from table2 in result set. So I created Below query that join my two table1 and table2.
My query:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.question,table1.posted_id,table2.email 
FROM table1,table2 
WHERE table1.post_id = table.id;
```

How to fix a left join on table 3 for filter the records Because I need questions which are not read by particular user.

Comment: You can have multiple `JOINS`: `LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.post_id=table2.id LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id=table3.quote_id`

Comment: What is quote_id in table3? is it the question id?

Comment: Nouphal yes it is question id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which user field you are trying to match against, i have taken email, Also this will only give matching records, Try

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.email
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T2.quote_id = T1.id
INNER JOIN Table3 AS T3 ON T3.reader_id = T2.id
WHERE T2.email='some_mail_id'
```